# Regex to capture a number OR a number between two underscores

Tags: java, regex

Due to combining a legacy platform with a newer one, we are at a point where we need a single regex expression that can capture two different types of input. 
This is clearly not great practice - and is going to be a temporary solution until we can smooth the integration out and go back to sanity.

The Regex expression must to have:

- Only one capturing group
- The global "greedy" flag is turned on, and we have no control over it
- It's implemented in Java

The two types of input:

1. Just a numeric ID. We need to capture all of it. Example: `12345678`
2. Numeric ID, underscore, numeric ID, underscore, numeric ID. We need the regex to capture the ID in the middle. Example: `997744_12345678_33557799`, and the expected result is `12345678`.

For input of type #1 only, the regex could have been `(\d+)`. For input of type #2 only, the regex could have been `\d+\_(\d+)\_\d+`. But as said - I need a single regex that can handle both.

I have tried to combine the two in several ways, like this:

`\d{0,}\_{0,1}(\d+)\_{0,1}\d{0,}` -> works for type #2, captures only last digit of type #1, because of greediness of the first expression

So tried to make the first expression non-greedy by adding `?`, getting this:

`\d{0,}?\_{0,1}(\d+)\_{0,1}\d{0,}` -> works for type #1, but captures the first and last IDs in type #2 instead of the one in the middle.

I am out of ideas, but am pretty sure that Regex is powerful rnough to do almost anything...

Comment: Can you give some examples for cases 1 & 2 ?

Comment: Do you need to validate input string while matching or it's just matching that matters at this point?

Comment: Check [`((?<=_)\d+(?=_)|\b\d+\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/8pKi5Q/2). Not sure you really need the outer capturing group, but you say there must be one.

Comment: So the whole thing is you can only use 1 capture group? What kind of junk is that ?

Comment: The quick answer is you have 2 distinct qualifications that can't be combined. Therefore you need two capture groups.  `(?<![\d_])(?:\d+_(\d+)_\d+|(\d+))(?![\d_])` It's a mistake to think it can be done with a single capture group. However, the answer is _always_ a cateneation of group 1 and 2. Sort of takes the brainwork out of it .. This pertains to Java, if variable length lookbehind it then can be done with a single capture group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be looking for [`(?:\d+_)?(\d+)(?:_\d+)?`](https://regex101.com/r/CIlydh/1)

[Java Demo](http://ideone.com/RvsqJ6)

Comment: Make side groups non-capturing [**`(?:\d+_)?(\d+)(?:_\d+)?`**](https://regex101.com/r/CIlydh/1)

Comment: I can only have one matching group - I have no control of the code at this point. I can only control the regex.

Comment: Revo's comment should do what you want :)

Comment: @revo Thanks for the suggestion. I updated my answer.

Comment: @revo posted a good solution - I need to check if we can support non-capturing groups. If yes - I'll accept this one

Comment: This answer also does not handle `123_456_789_256` number correctly.

Comment: Just put right anchors [**`^(?:\d+_)?(\d+)(?:_\d+)?$`**](https://regex101.com/r/MttAl4/2) @MaxZoom

Comment: *The two types of input: 1- **Just** a numeric ID....* so I think my assumptions would be right if OP needs to go for a validation layer. @MaxZoom

Comment: It also matches `997744_12345678`.

Comment: I guess it could be lookahead qualified if using anchors. `^(?=(?:\d+_\d+_\d+|\d+)$)(?:\d+_)?(\d+)(?:_\d+)?$` but not if it has to match within a substring. But, why try to make regex _bend_ to your will. Use 2 capture groups.